# Angular 4 Animation variable style support

Tags: angular

I have a particularly difficult animation that I'm trying to achieve and the only way I can think of to achieve it is to get the style to reference a variable I can update before triggering the animation.

A user can click to expand a section which contains a collection of elements (which in turn can be expanded causing the height of the animation to change). This collection is not static and the user can use basic CRUD actions on the data which means after the section is opened it's height can change. So the idea is when the section has x items the height is y, I can easily do the calculations to determine the correct height given the number of items in the collection however I've been unable to find any support for variable styles. I saw some mention from about a year ago that it was coming but nothing more recent. Does anyone know if angular has added support for this yet, and if so where I can find the documentation?

Since I know someone will suggest it, yes I've tried the max-height trick and it just doesn't work. The issue is the section could be 200 pixels tall or a few thousand pixels tall, so I choose something safe for the max-height like 10000 pixels. So now for example the actual height of a section ends up being say 200px, the max-height was set to 10000px and the animation time was 500ms. So now when the user clicks to close the section the majority of the animation appears to have nothing happening because it's doing the 9800 pixels of extra space that wasn't displayed. Then in the final few ms the last 200px start animating VERY fast. This isn't any better than just having the section appear/disappear without any animation at all and really due to the delay is worse.

**Update**
Here's a plunker example of my final solution thanks the the answer below. https://plnkr.co/edit/o7bnbiDcHZ3U333txbwU?p=preview

Couple of key lines from that example:

This one is pretty easy to find online and works fine if you intend the element to be expanded on load.

```
state('1', style({
  height: '*',
  padding: '10px'
})),
```

However if you need to have the element collapsed on load you'll also need this transition.

```
transition('void => *', animate(0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-selector',
  ...  
  animations: [
    trigger('slideDown', [
        state('0', style({ height: '0px', overflow: 'hidden' })),

        // '*' lets you animate to any height or other numeric property
        state('1', style({ height: '*', overflow: 'hidden'  })), 

        // this gets you to the default "hidden" state
        transition('void => *', [    
            animate(0)
        ]),

        transition('* => *', [
            animate('300ms ease-in-out')
        ])
    ])
  ]
```

on your html template:

```
<div [@slideDown]="slideDown"> where slideDown is a boolean </div>
```

You'll need to import the animation module in your `app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
```

for more info: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/kP14stY51DBUQhMezFmC?p=preview

Comment: Unfortinitly that doesn't work as it required 2 things.

1) This only works if the height is a constant, the height for mine is constantly changing based on user interactions.
2) The item needs to start in it's expanded state so that the height can be determined. I need it to start collapsed.

Comment: edited answer based on your comment and added a plunker

Comment: your plunkr does not have [@slideDown]="slideDown" notation anywhere in the html. My problem isnt exactly the same as the original post but was looking for that implementation and you dont have it

Comment: @SamAlexander i used `peek` in my plunker

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngStyle to achieve what you are looking for:

`[ngStyle]="{height: noOfElements > 1 ? elemHeight  : '40px'}"`

where noOfElements and elemHeight  are variable defined in your typescript file. please let me know if you need further help.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but after thinking it through for a while I don't think this will work. The main issue I see why this wouldn't work is it just sets the height based on the number of elements, it in no way animates the height form 0 to that height and doesn't work at all with either Angular Animation or CSS Transition. This would work as a toggle from 0 height to the full height without animation but I want it to transition smoothly

Comment: you can use this to height the container and use the animations for the elements inside it.